# Splitting a dictionary within a list python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have the a dictionary within a list

```
[{'123': 'some text'}]
```

I want my output to be a string with the keys and values separated like so

```
'123', 'some text'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_list_dict = [{'123': 'some text'}]

for elem in my_list_dict:
    for key in elem:
        print('key:', key)
        print('value:', elem[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the values into the list, right? 
Here is my aprouch

```
    list_dict = [{'123': 'some text'}]
    list_without_dict = []
    for dict in list_dict:
      for key in dict:
        list_without_dict.append(key)
        list_without_dict.append(dict[key])

    print(list_without_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

simply iterate over the whole of your input keeping the keys and values and use `', '.join()` to join a list into a string with ", " as a delimiter

```
wierd_input = [{'123': 'some text', 'foo':'boo'}, {'and':'another'}]

all_parts = []
for dictionary in wierd_input:
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        all_parts.extend((key, value))

print(", ".join(all_parts))

>>123, some text, foo, boo, and, another
```

you can convert this into a generator if you want to join such objects frequently in your code

```
def iterate_over_wierd(wierd):
    for dictionary in wierd:
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            yield key
            yield value

print(", ".join(iterate_over_wierd(wierd_input)))
```

if you desperately need a one-liner you can use itertools

```
import itertools
', '.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items,wierd_input))))
```

but I advise against this as the one liner is very confusing and hacky, better stick to the former two